# How to Label patch in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, label, patch

I am plotting rectangular patches in matplotlib in interactive mode. I want to add text to each patch. I do not want to annotate them as it decreases the speed. I am using 'label' property of patch but it is not working. Ayone know how to add 1 string to patch.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches

plt.ion()
plt.show()

x = y = 0.1
fig1 = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(111, aspect='equal')
patch = ax1.add_patch(patches.Rectangle((x, y), 0.5, 0.5,
    alpha=0.1,facecolor='red',label='Label'))

plt.pause(0)
plt.close()
```

Comment: If you want the label to be displayed you need to call `plt.legend()`.

Comment: You might want to [look at this example from the docs](http://matplotlib.org/users/text_props.html)  It shows you how to add text at various points within a patch. If you really want to display all your existing labels in a legend - see `plt.legend()`

Comment: Patches are arbitrary Artist objects, so `plt.legend()` is not what you want. If you want visible text over the object, use either `plt.text()` or `plt.annotate()`. In matplotlib, `label` is not a a visible text label, it's an internal 'handle' for finding objects of subclass Artist with `plt.findobj()`, but that doesn't seem to work on patches.

Answer (score 15):

You already know where the patch is, so you can calculate where the center is and add some text there:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches

x=y=0.1
fig1 = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(111, aspect='equal')
patch= ax1.add_patch(patches.Rectangle((x, y), 0.5, 0.5,
    alpha=0.1,facecolor='red',label='Label'))

centerx = centery = x + 0.5/2 # obviously use a different formula for different shapes

plt.text(centerx, centery,'lalala')
plt.show()
```

[image: centeredtext]

The coordinates for `plt.text` determine where the text begins, <strike>so you can nudge it a bit in the x direction to get the text to be more centered e.g. `centerx - 0.05`.</strike> *obviously @JoeKington's suggestion is the proper way of achieving this*

Comment: `annotate` gives a more powerful API to this sort of thing.

Comment: You'd typically specify `horizontalalignment="center"` (or more compactly, `ha="center"`) to center the text instead of nudging coordinates.

Comment: I obviously should have known that...Acknowledged accordingly!

Comment: @areuexperienced , thanks for your answer. I am plotting data that is coming from sensor so plotting is in infinite loop. If I add text/annotate object it decrease speed. I want to use label attribute of patch just like explain in this link but I am not able to understand.
http://matplotlib.org/examples/shapes_and_collections/artist_reference.html

Comment: @Luqman , in the example you've posted `label` is simply a function that calls `plt.text`, so it's the same as what I've shown. It is different that the `label` argument that gets passed to the patch you're making, which is to do with `plt.legend`.